# Combinated query in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

i have table **Employess**:

```
|id|datetime           |in-out|
|1 |2015-03-03 06:00:00|in    |
|1 |2015-03-03 14:15:00|out   |
|1 |2015-03-04 06:00:00|in    |
|1 |2015-03-04 15:00:00|out   |
```

I want **create view** with information how long work employees(id) such that

```
|id|datetime_in        |datetime_out       |how_log|
|1 |2015-03-03 06:00:00|2015-03-03 14:00:00|08:15  |
|1 |2015-03-04 06:00:00|2015-03-03 15:00:00|09:00  |
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way to get the result you are after - by using `pivot` clause(Oracle 11g and up):

```
select id
     , to_char(in1, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')  as datetime_in
     , to_char(out1, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as datetime_out
     , to_char(extract(hour from numtodsinterval(out1-in1, 'day'))
              , 'fm00') || ':' || 
       to_char(extract(minute from numtodsinterval(out1-in1, 'day'))
              , 'fm00')                       as how_long
  from ( select id
              , datetime
              , in_out 
              , row_number() over(partition by id, in_out
                                  order by datetime) as rn
          from tb1   
         order by datetime
      )
pivot (
  max(datetime) for in_out in ('in' as in1, 'out' as out1)
)
order by id, datetime_in
```

Result:

```
        ID DATETIME_IN         DATETIME_OUT        HOW_LONG
---------- ------------------- ------------------- --------
         1 2015-03-03 06:00:00 2015-03-03 14:15:00 08:15    
         1 2015-03-04 06:00:00 2015-03-04 15:00:00 09:00
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ee476/1)

Comment: It works great, but i have problem, when in table i have NULL value. Could you look for this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f8db8/1/0

Comment: @starko So, an employee has an `in` time but has no `out` time (or the other way around)? What result do you expect in this situation?

Comment: @starko Then you can simply use `nvl()` or `coalesce()` function to deal with `null`'s [here is an example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f8db8/3)of "copying" `in` time if the `out` one happens to be `null`.

Answer (score 2):

If you assume that the "in"s and "out"s alternate, you can just get the next value:

```
select e.id, e.datetime as datetime_in, datetime_out,
       (floor((datetime_out - datetime_in)*24) || ':' ||
        mod(floor((datetime_out - datetime_in * 24*60), 60)
       ) as timediff
from (select e.*, lead(datetime) over (order by partition by id order by datetime) as datetime_out
      from employees e
     ) e
where in_out = 'in'
```